# Custom hostname for Composer private repository URL

Tags: git, github, ssh, composer-php

⇒ I configured a secondary SSH key in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host custom-git-host
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/secondary_id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

⇒ Then, I cloned a repository from GitHub using the secondary SSH credentials, example:

```
git clone git@custom-git-host:repo/codebase
```

⇒ The `composer.json` have a private repository added, example:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "git@github.com:repo/package-1.git",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try `composer install`, it shows that the 'repository cannot be read' (since the default ssh cannot access the private repo).

⇒ If I deleted the existing lock file and changed the repo URL to use the secondary SSH, it works:

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "git@custom-git-host:repo/package-1.git",
            "type": "git"
        }
    ]
}
```

⇒ But, the problem is that the repository does have a `composer.lock` file and the private repository URL is also recorded in it as 'git@github.com:repo/package-1.git'. So, as long as the lock file stays, `composer install` uses the `git@github.com:repo/package-1.git` URL.

**What to do in such cases? Does composer have the option to replace 'github.com' hostname with 'custom-git-host'? Is temporarily replacing the hostname in both the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` the only way? Or is there a completely unrelated solution for this?**

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) configuration:

> `url.<base>.insteadOf`
>
> Any URL that starts with this value will be rewritten to start, instead, with `<base>`. In cases where some site serves a large number of repositories, and serves them with multiple access methods, and some users need to use different access methods, this feature allows people to specify any of the equivalent URLs and have Git automatically rewrite the URL to the best alternative for the particular user, even for a never-before-seen repository on the site. When more than one insteadOf strings match a given URL, the longest match is used.
>
> Note that any protocol restrictions will be applied to the rewritten URL. If the rewrite changes the URL to use a custom protocol or remote helper, you may need to adjust the `protocol.*.allow` config to permit the request. In particular, protocols you expect to use for submodules must be set to `always` rather than the default of `user`. See the description of `protocol.allow` above.

So for your case it would be:

```
git config url."git@custom-git-host".insteadOf "git@github.com"
```

Comment: That's a neat solution, but may be for a different problem :) It doesn't seem to work with `composer install`. Still getting: `Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- 'git@github.com:repo/package-1.git' '/home/user/.cache/composer/vcs/git-github.com-repo-package-1.git/'`. Even after deleting the lock file, it is still using the original URL as given in the `composer.json`.

Comment: May be the `insteadOf` needs to be set globally for GIT. But then that'll cause issues in my other repo clones...